# How to show last screen of Youtube Video when youtube video finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, youtube-api

I am adding youtube video link in my web application using following JavaScript code.
This is working Fine.
But when Video finishes by default youtube video gives other links divided in small square boxes, **I dont want this**.

**When video finishes then black screen should appear or whatever is the end screen there in video should appear.**

**Can we do this? If yes then how?**

```
youtubeLoadVideos : function () {
    var videos = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube");
        for (var i=0; i<videos.length; i++) {
            var youtube = videos[i];
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + youtube.id);

            // The height and width of the iFrame should be the same as parent
            iframe.style.width = youtube.style.width;
            iframe.style.height = youtube.style.height;
            iframe.style.clear = 'both';
            youtube.parentNode.appendChild(iframe, youtube);
            //youtube.appendChild(youtube.id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + youtube.id + "?rel=0");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `?rel=0` to your URL, or disable "Show suggested videos when the video finishes"

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you above is working fine. But can we remove the "Youtube" branding?